# Google API 3 contacts, convert array of strings to key value pairs

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to convert the emails that I retrieved from google API contacts

**basically I just want to convert this array of emails**

```
["pragya.bajracharya@longtailux.com.au",
"support+id34845@autopilothq.zendesk.com",
"john.concepcion@microsourcing.com",
"reinagonzales@sharpmindscontent.com"]
```

**into this**

```
{email: 'nikola@tesla.com'},
{email: 'brian@thirdroute.com'},
{email: 'gilbert@spacer.com'},
{email: 'someone@gmail.com'}
```

below is the code i used how to retrieve the emails from google contacts

```js
function auth() {
     var config = {
       'client_id': 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
     };
     gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
       fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());  
      
     });
   }
 
   var fetch =function fetch(token) {
     $.ajax({
      url:"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=10000&access_token=" + token.access_token,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success:function(data) {
          // display all your data in console   
          var emailAddresses = JSON.stringify(data.feed.entry.map(function(entry) {
              //take the first gd$email item the entry has
              var gdEmail =   entry['gd$email'][0];
              //this assumes all entries will have a gd$email, 
              var emails =  gdEmail.address;
              return emails;
          }));
         console.log(emailAddresses);
      }
  });
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="auth();">GET CONTACTS FEED</button>
```

this is the sample result from console.log(emailAddresses);

```
["pragya.bajracharya@longtailux.com.au",
"support+id34845@autopilothq.zendesk.com",
"john.concepcion@microsourcing.com",
"reinagonzales@sharpmindscontent.com"]
```

Comment: `emailaddress.each(function(in, val){newarr.push('email':val)});`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, can your answer be more detailed?

Comment: Write above code after your consloe.log , still if you get any error in browser console, please share error detail

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gbx49k there seems to be a problem with the code

Comment: Check updated code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var emailaddress = ["pragya.bajracharya@longtailux.com.au",
  "support+id34845@autopilothq.zendesk.com",
  "john.concepcion@microsourcing.com",
  "reinagonzales@sharpmindscontent.com"
];

console.log(emailaddress);

var newarr = [];
// Loop through all email address and push to new array with your key
emailaddress.forEach(function(val, index) {
  newarr.push({
    "email": val
  })
});

console.log(newarr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

You're stringy array, so it's not working.

Use below code instead

```
 var emailAddresses = data.feed.entry.map(function(entry) {
      //take the first gd$email item the entry has
      var gdEmail =   entry['gd$email'][0];
      //this assumes all entries will have a gd$email, 
      var emails =  gdEmail.address;
      return emails;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm still receiving error referral:692 Uncaught TypeError: emailAddresses.forEach is not a function
http://prntscr.com/gby417

Comment: It should work.. can you check emailAddress is array?

Comment: this is the response:
["p.vanschyndel@criteo.com","tim.lucke@gmail.com","SupportMMSAU@criteo.com","support+id27018@autopilothq.zendesk.com","tech@spacer.com.au","lisaw@prgroup.com.au","support@hsselite.com","steve.miholovich@safenames.net"]

Comment: @Bertlucas Just remove `JSON.stringify` from your above sample. It will work then